# I cannot get white space to disappear using accordion and jquery on bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

Here is a test page i am working on.  Please forgive the mess, it is a test page from half template/half customized and using it to test code.  When you scroll down and open and close the accordion, it leaves white space at the bottom of the entire page unless you click the last question on the accordion.

Nothing seems to work from google, here, and everything I try.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

this didn't work either as other posts I saw around: `heightStyle: "content"` or `autoHeight: false`

Comment: I see unexpected content on DOM
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -10000; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 5842px;"></div>

Comment: There is a div adding dynamically when you click on the accordion so just inspect that and do not create it. This will fix your problem.

Comment: how do you get rid of it then?.  Also, this line '<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -10000; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; height: 5842px;"></div>' is not in my html.  It just appears out of nowhere.  Not quite understanding, sorry.   The "5842px" will change each time depending on which tab is open.

Comment: fixed - See answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

Well it's fixed. Got some help from others.  I had a js file called smoothscroll.min.js that had some code that looked like this:

```
....right:0; height:"+X.scrollHeight+"px",document.body.appendChild(r)...
```

and by changing it to this:

```
....right:0; height:"100%",document.body.appendChild(r)...
```

it seems to work now!! :)